# Grails keep on giving null pointer exception

Tags: jquery, grails

Before the body tag

```
      var wall = new freewall(".freewall");
      wall.reset({
        selector: '.grid-tile',
        animate: false,
            cellW: 200,
          cellH: 'auto',
          delay: 1,
        onResize: function() {
          wall.fitWidth();
          wall.refresh();
        }
      });
         wall.fitWidth();  
  var temp ='';
         temp += '<div class="grid-tile">';
         temp += '<a class="overlay" href="/portfolio/${portfolio?.id}">';
         temp += '<span class="title">${portfolio?.title}</span>';
         temp += '<span>by ${portfolio?.ownerName}</span><div class="category">Project log</div>';

         temp += '<img src="${portfolio?.coverImage()}" width="100%" /><hr/><p>${portfolio?.title}</p>';


        $(".add-more").click(function () {
          for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
                 console.log(temp);
                $(temp).appendTo('.freewall');
              }

        });
</g:javascript>
```

**Html**

```
<div id="freewall" class="grd freewall">
                %{-- <div class="grid-sizer"></div> --}%
                <g:each in="${list}" var="portfolio" max="10">

                    <div class="grid-tile">
                        <a class="overlay" href="/portfolio/${portfolio.id}">

                            <span class="title">${portfolio.title}</span>
                            <span>by ${portfolio.ownerName}</span>
                            <div class="category">Test</div>

                        </a>
                        <img src="${portfolio?.coverImage()}" width="100%" />
                                                    <hr/>
                                                    <p>${portfolio.title}</p>
                    </div>
                </g:each>

                </div>


    </div>
<div class="push"></div>
</div>
  <div class="add-more">

    <h2>See more</h2>

</div>
```

I am trying freewall in dynamic grails template. Static works pretty well but not grails :(
**Update**

Managed to get it working with string, but ${portfolio?.coverImage()} seems not to be appended to img tag.. :(

Help appreciated

Comment: Looks like `portfolio` is `null`. Check its value.

Comment: @techfoobar - if i remove the js code, it displays the images and overlay fine, but if i add in js code, it shows npe.

Comment: In your JS code, you are referring to the `portfolio` variable, assumably passed in from the controller. Check the value of `portfolio` that you are passing to the model.

Comment: Where is the JS in the HTML ? The `portfolio` variable is only valid under the `<g:each in="${list}" var="portfolio" max="10">`tag. It's not coming from the conttroller (it seems the `list` variable does, though)

Comment: @Grooveek - the js u see is in before html body tag.

Comment: @techfoobar yes check already and it worked now only problem is coverimage() is not appended to the freewall :(

Comment: @techfoobar how come the string cannot access to the items that need to be appended?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that you are not doing the iteration in the good place. Either you iterate via `g:each` in the html with hidden elements, and you adapt your JS code, or you make your iteration in JS
The clearer solution will be the first one, that is to adapt your JS code to handle your 10 templates written as you show in the HTML

**JS CODE**

```
$(".add-more").click(function () {      
  //iterate over the templates
  $("#templates > div.grid-tile").each(function(){             
         console.log(this);
        $(this).appendTo('.freewall');
      });

});
```

**HTML CODE**

```
        <div id⁼"templates" style="display:none">
           <g:each in="${list}" var="portfolio" max="10">

                <div class="grid-tile">
                    <a class="overlay" href="/portfolio/${portfolio.id}">

                        <span class="title">${portfolio.title}</span>
                        <span>by ${portfolio.ownerName}</span>
                        <div class="category">Test</div>

                    </a>
                    <img src="${portfolio?.coverImage()}" width="100%" />
                                                <hr/>
                                                <p>${portfolio.title}</p>
                </div>
            </g:each>
       </div>
```

The second solution would be less clean

```
 //creates an array to store items
 var coverImages = array();
  <g:each in="${list}" var="portfolio" max="10" status="idx">
     //here, you write to the JS output N variables named temp_0, temp_1, etc
     var temp_${idx} ='';
     temp_${idx} += '<div class="grid-tile">';
     temp_${idx} += '<a class="overlay" href="/portfolio/${portfolio?.id}">';
     temp_${idx} += '<span class="title">${portfolio?.title}</span>';
     temp_${idx} += '<span>by ${portfolio?.ownerName}</span><div class="category">Project log</div>';

     temp_${idx} += '<img src="${portfolio?.coverImage()}" width="100%" /><hr/><p>${portfolio?.title}</p>';
     //don't forget to add the temp_$idx var to the array
     coverImages.push(temp_${idx})
  </g:each>

    $(".add-more").click(function () {
      //iterate over the array
      for (var i in coverImages) {
             var temp = coverImages[i]
             console.log(temps);
            $(temp).appendTo('.freewall');
          }

    });
```

The problem is taht the JS code produced will be messy. Because you'll have something like :

```
var temp_0 ='';
     temp_0 += '<div class="grid-tile">';
     temp_0 += '<a class="overlay" href="/portfolio/${portfolio?.id}">';
     temp_0 += '<span class="title">${portfolio?.title}</span>';
     temp_0 += '<span>by ${portfolio?.ownerName}</span><div class="category">Project log</div>';

     temp_0 += '<img src="${portfolio?.coverImage()}" width="100%" /><hr/><p>${portfolio?.title}</p>';
     coverImages.push(temp_0)
 var temp_1 ='';
     temp_1 += '<div class="grid-tile">';
     temp_1 += '<a class="overlay" href="/portfolio/${portfolio?.id}">';
     temp_1 += '<span class="title">${portfolio?.title}</span>';
     temp_1 += '<span>by ${portfolio?.ownerName}</span><div class="category">Project log</div>';

     temp_1 += '<img src="${portfolio?.coverImage()}" width="100%" /><hr/><p>${portfolio?.title}</p>';
     coverImages.push(temp_1)
```

10 times... (I think you'll have to insert `\n` under each iteration, I haven't checked)

Code shown here hasn't been tested.... Adapt it to your needs

Comment: lets say i wanna append 10 images each time click button provided that there are more images like .. 400? would your code work? i am giving it a try now

Comment: This code was for a 1 time shot. You click your button, 10 images are added, then you can disable it or it will append the same 10 more images at each click. But that's not the problem you were talking about in your question, it's purely javascript related. You should explain your new needs in a new question. What are your needs ?

Comment: tried your code and tweaked, but it is not working as expected. plus grails template displays alot of temp string.

Comment: not working as expected is pretty vague... Which solution have you picked out and what goes wrong?

Comment: Tried solution #1 - clicking on button, it does nothing. Solution #2 displays all temp strings (refer to after var coverImages = array();).. mmm..

Comment: [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4uj6/6/) illustrates point #1. Check that the markup generated by Grails is the same. That was the goal of my code. But I can't check that on a grails project, sorry